# How to enable dark mode on react native webview?

Tags: android, css, ios, react-native, webview

One of the [issues in react native](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/pull/2063) webview says "On iOS the WebView automatically uses the dark-theme if the system appearance is set to dark. On Android this is not happening." also there's a PR created (which is still to be merged as of today). But wanted to know how to actually enable dark mode in ios webviews like it's mentioned. It doesn't happen automatically while toggling system level theme.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?